# Remove spaces from a user input String

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a code to remove spaces in a user input String, but I receive an error at line 16.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   15 at practice5.main(practice5.java:16)

Note: We are not allowed to use the replace method of Java. I need to code it manually.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class practice5{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line;
        System.out.print("Sentence: ");
        line = scanner.nextLine();
        char phrase[] = line.toCharArray();
        int i = 0;
        int n = 0;

        while(phrase[i] != '\0') {
            if(phrase[i] == ' ') {
                for(n=i; n<phrase.length; n++) {
                    phrase[n] = phrase[n+1];
                }
            }
            i++;
        }

        String output = new String(phrase);
        System.out.print(output);
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You have to stop your Loop , if you reach the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function of the String class. Just use line.replace(" ","")

Comment: Hi, my professor requires us to code it manually. But thank you, I will search it up.

Comment: Then you need the stop the loop e.g. 
if(i>phrase.length) break;

Answer (score 1):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   15 at practice5.main(practice5.java:16)

The ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown when a call to an array element is made at an index that does not exist.

In your code, at line 16, you are calling `phrase[n+1]` which works fine for all cases except when `n==(phrase.length-1)` because then n+1 will be equal to `phrase.length`.

Length is counted starting from 1 whereas indices are counted starting from 0. Therefore, during the last iteration, `phrase[n+1]` is equivalent to `phrase[phrase.length]` which is an out of bound index.

You can correct it by reducing the loop iterations by 1.

Comment: Hi, may I ask if every time the characters move, here: phrase[n] = phrase[n+1]; does the phrase.length get smaller as well? Also, thank you for your response. I understand what you're saying but I'm still not sure how to code this :/ I tried for(n = i-1; n < phrase.length; n++), but I still get the same error.

Comment: @Katrina your loop needs to be 'for(n=i;n<phrase.length-1;n++). The reason is because you don't want you index (in this case n) to be equal to or greater than the length.

Comment: Hi @adeen-s, I tried this as well, and I still get the same error :(

Answer (score 1):

**Reason for error:ArrayIndexOutOfBound**

suppose yor sentence is: **abc**.Now when you will execute your code...this is happening...

1st iteration: **i** is on the index 0(i.e at a).2nd iteration,**i** is on index 1 (i.e at b) and on 3rd iteration,**i** is on index 3 (on c),and again **i** is incremented by 1,so now **i=4**.Now

```
while(phrase[i]!='\0')
```

will return such exception because you are comparing value at index 4 while is not available.Hence,such exception is occuring.

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code it may help

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line;
    System.out.print("Sentence: ");
    line = scanner.nextLine();
    char phrase[] = line.toCharArray();
    String result = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++) {
        if (phrase[i] != ' ') {
            result += phrase[i];
        }           
    }

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: working good if the requirement is not to save it in char array all the time. also you can delete the continue, if you move the += inside the if and negate the condition

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel? Just use String's [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) method:

```
String output = line.replace(" ", "");
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, but my professor requires that we code it manually :)

Comment: @Katrina you should add this piece of information to your question, so others can post their answers in regard to that.

Comment: You're right, I'll edit it in now. I didn't realize a method existed for it already. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `CharMatcher` to determine

> whether a character is whitespace according to the latest Unicode
>   standard

```
CharMatcher.whitespace().trimAndCollapseFrom("user input","");
```